# I'm getting a non-stop error when I run this .py file [Sel

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate outlook emails, but sadly I came to a stop because I'm  getting this non-stop error.

```
op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

I looked back at my previous selenium projects and it works, I copied it but deleting useless code for my outlook email bot. I still get a error, but on my old project, no.

Even if I make the argument a comment it brings another one with another argument error. Here is my code (I'm not finished finding the elements, but if someone finds the problem that would mean a lot):

```
#imports
import os, time, random, spintax, requests, config
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from random import randint, randrange
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#var
email1tf = False
email2tf = False
email3tf = False
email4tf = False
email1 = 'example@email.com'
email2 = 'example@email.com'
email3 = 'example@email.com'
email4 = 'example@email.com'

#main
PROXY = "3.88.169.225:80"

print("(!) Wait 10 Seconds. (!)")
time.sleep(10)

myemail = config.myemail
mypassword = config.mypassword

def stop(n):
    time.sleep(randint(2, n))

def outlook(myemail,mypassword):

    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    # op.add_argument('--headless')
    op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    op.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    # op.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    op.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    op.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    # op.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    # op.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op, executable_path= 'chromedriver.exe')
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")

    driver.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com') #place outlook login page
    time.sleep(7)
    print(f"Got on a link called 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'")
    print("=============================================================================================================")
    print("On the Outlook Login Page")

    email_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    email_field.send_keys(myemail)
    driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
    print("Email - Done")
    stop(5)

    pass_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    pass_field.send_keys(mypassword)
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()


    return driver
    
    driver.quit()

def email(driver):

    #checking if the emails are already sent to the user
    while True:
        if email1tf == True and email2tf == True and email3tf == True and email4tf == True:
            print("DONE")
        else:
            ###


if __name__ == '__main__':

    driver = outlook(myemail, mypassword)
```

Comment: the issue is that your code has mixed use of tabs and spaces for indentation. You should use only either of them. Easy fix open your code in VS code. Open the command and search for `convert indentation to spaces`. To avoid this issue in future also set `indent using spaces` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this code and I found no error. If your error is

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

then it's not an error.
It's just a formatting problem. If you use VSCode you can convert all your indentations to tab from spaces if there are any

[image]

After clicking it, you'll be given the option of using spaces or tabs to indent. Click on indent using tabs.